If $G$ acts on $X$ transitively, then $G_{gx}=gG_xg^{-1}$
I am reading Serre's Finite Groups: An Introduction and there is a remark which reads: If a group $G$ acts on a set $X$ transitively, and if $x\in X$, we have a bijection from $G/G_x\rightarrow X$ given by $gG_x\mapsto gx$. If $x'\in X$, there exists $g\in G$ such that $x'=gx$. Thus, $G_{x'}=gG_xg^{-1}$.
I am having troubles to understand the 'thus' part. While I can prove the two sets $G_{x'}, gG_xg^{-1}$ are equal (by letting $h\in G_{x'}$, then show $h\in gG_xg^{-1}$ and conversely), I have troubles to see why Serre can just write that out simply. Am I missing something and is there a much easier proof?

This is because we always have (not assuming a transitive action)
$$
G_{gx}=gG_xg^{-1},
$$
see here: The stabiliser of $g.x$ is the subgroup $gGxg^{-1}$.
Since now $gx=x'$, we can say "Thus, $G_{x'}=G_{gx}=gG_xg^{-1}$."
